# Save file to local disk after controller action fires, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

It seems to be a popular question, although I couldn't find final solution.

I'd like to save `.xml` file after some data has been written into DB in my controller.
My view contains `Html.BeginForm()` and in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(StatementModel model)
{
   //saving data to db
   //...
   //tried to save file with Response
  string text = model.content;
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ClearHeaders();
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", text.Length.ToString());
  Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"test.xml\"");

  Response.Write(text);
  Response.End();

  //redirect is not firing
  return RedirectToAction("Companies");
}
```

This might be a bad idea, because my redirect is not working. Can you advise other approach? I guess I can handle it with jQuery on ajax submit. Will it be necessarily to use ajax form instead of html? Also, I couldn't find the script for saving file with dialog in jQuery.

**EDIT**
Using jquery ajax:

```
<script>
 function call() {
    var msg = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Statements")',
        data: msg,  
        success: function (data) {
            //not firing
            console.log('submitted');
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Customers", "Statements")';
        },
        error: function (xhr, str) {
            alert(xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
$("form").submit(function () {
    call();
});
</script>
<form method="post" target="_blank"> ... <form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(StatementModel model)
{ 
      if(ModelState.IsValid)
      {
           // saving file ...
           Response.Write(text);
           Response.End();
      }
      return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now the file is saved in new window. But I cannot redirect to another page in `success` function. It is not firing. Is it because I use html form? Then if using ajax form how can I open new page?

Answer (score 1):

Each HTTP request can only have one response - you're trying to sneak in two (the file, and a page).

Normally when you send a "Content-Disposition: attachment" HTTP header the browser will stay on the current page and pop a file save dialog (or automatically save the file in your downloads).

You're going to have to change your strategy. open this page (download file) in a new window and make redirect using javascript.

**Edited**

In your Controller you can set Response status

```
if(..Success..) 
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
else
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
```

using ajax you can check status code

```
$.ajax({
    //...        
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        aler(xhr.status);
    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        alert(xhr.status);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thank u, and how can I handle modelstate errors? I need to redirect after the action completes successfully. Should I do this in onSuccess, onError in $.ajax()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Response.End()` try using   `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`

Comment: In this case the save file dialog is not opening.